# Android: setting custom view's text color with tab layout's style

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I am using tab layouts with custom view in some fragments and I want the custom view's text color to be set from the tab layout style (as the custom view would be reused at different places and with different text colors, I want the different stylings of the tab layouts to set the colors). I have not defined any text colors in the custom view, still the text is always shown black instead of white, which is set in the tab layout style.

Codes:

Tab layout style:

```
<style name="TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/secondary_bg_color</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/tab_indicator_color</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">@dimen/tab_height</item>
    <item name="tabGravity">fill</item>
    <item name="tabTextColor">@color/white_text_color</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/white_text_color</item>
</style>
```

Custom view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_padding_bottom"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_padding_top">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_title"
        style="@style/TabLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/payment_tab_padding_left" />

</LinearLayout>
```

TabLabel style:

```
<style name="TabLabel">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textsize_caption</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">textStart</item>
</style>
```

Usage:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/primary_bg_color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/bf_fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/outgoing_tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TabBar"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

What is going wrong? Why doesn't the tab layout's text color have any effect on the text color of the custom view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because tabTextColor y tabSelectedTextColor only works with the default textView of the tab but it doesn't work with custom tabs. You can see this behaviour in the source implementation of TabLayout.

You need to handle the text colors of custom tabs by yourself.

Comment: Hi Yiyo, can you elaborate on how to handle text colors on the custom tab?